# does "what does she do?" always mean "what is her job?"

Tags: present-tense, formal-language, informal-language

If someone asks "What does she do?" what is the other meaning beside "what is her job?"? can it be " what is her activity?"

Comment: "What does she do *for a living*?" means "What is her job?" and "What does she do?" can mean any activity she does.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some suggestions for answers to the question

> What does she do?

The items of bold text below are the section names in the entry for **do** in the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/do):

> **deal with**
>   She is doing the lighting for the school play
>
> **study**
>   She is doing anthropology at university.
>
> **travel** (if she is a car or boat)
>   She'll do over a hundred miles an hour
>
> **clean/make tidy**
>   She did my nails last week
>
> **cook**
>   She can do you some scrambled eggs.
>
> **play** (acting)
>   She does television sitcoms
>
> **take drug**
>   She does heroin